# What causes this error? NFT Minting via Piniata - fails transaction

Tags: solidity, hardhat, nft, nodejs

Every time i submit my form from my frontend, MM opens up so i can pay my fee, i click confirm, the transaction fails with the error:

```
 {"blockHash":"0x837e462b489e65282e3a7c1b7f524cfc9c32bfa291c04940981323c9f1193606","blockNumber":"19613905","cumulativeGasUsed":"21070","from":"0x1d1874f9bcea4400a6a3ed85353bf19a764534e5","gasUsed":"21070","logs":[],"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","status":"0","to":"0x73ba4c37ce620ce4f7883ed4fcdf289c5448628b","transactionHash":"0x356fbf55537ab622ae6bac0e211a04276616b6806d64a158dfe0cc3631f6a554","transactionIndex":"0"}
    at get_transaction_error.ts:58:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at get_revert_reason.ts:94:2
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter29 (get_revert_reason.ts:94:2)
    at getTransactionError (get_transaction_error.ts:41:67)
    at rpc_method_wrappers.ts:630:28
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (get_transaction_error.ts:93:2)
```

I dont know how to solve this issue, I rewrote my backend multiple times and now i just started loosing hope...
The project was supposed to enable user to upload an image and mint an NFT with it using piñata ipfs pinning service and I'm using a proprietary L2 blockchain to run the tx's.
Here is my supper simple contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract SimpleNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    event Minted(address indexed recipient, uint256 tokenId, string uri);

    constructor() ERC721("SimpleNFT", "SNFT") {}

    function mintNFT(
        address recipient,
        string memory uri
    ) external returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newNftTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newNftTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newNftTokenId, uri);

        emit Minted(recipient, newNftTokenId, uri);

        return newNftTokenId;
    }
}
```

My frontend form that is supposed to be used to upload, mint and title the nfts: (i wont post the abi)

```
const contractAddress = "0x227d23545A2B53dEF6A9e68402482534Fd9cb961";

const Form = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [imgURL, setImgURL] = useState(null);
  const [title1, setTitle1] = useState("");
  const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
        setContract(contractInstance);
      } else {
        console.error("Ethereum provider not found");
      }
    };
    init();
  }, []);

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
    console.log("Selected File:", selectedFile);
    setFile(selectedFile);
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
    setImgURL(objectURL);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleSubmit triggered");
    if (file) {
      try {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log("File found, attempting to mint NFT...");
        const txReceipt = await contract.methods
          .mintNFT(accounts[0], title1)
          .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 500000 });
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("title", title1);
        formData.append("address", accounts[0]);
        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3000/api/mint",
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );
        console.log("Minting Response:", txReceipt);
        console.log("Minting Response:", response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during minting process:", error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("No file selected");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="nftbg">
        <div className="newnft">
          <p className="p1">CREATE</p>
          <p className="p2"> &nbsp;NEW NFT</p>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <section>
            <label htmlFor="file">Import file</label>
            <input
              type="file"
              name="file"
              id="file"
              onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
            <div className="photo_container">
              <img src={imgURL} alt="profile picture preview" />
            </div>
          </section>
          <section>
            <label htmlFor="title">NFT title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title1"
              id="title1"
              onChange={(e) => setTitle1(e.target.value)}
            />
          </section>
          <button type="submit" className="btn_NFT">
            <p className="btn_text_NFT">✨ Create Now ✨</p>
          </button>
        </form>
        <div className="bar">
          <p>Additional NFTs details</p>
          <div className="arrow"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

And my backend i use to upload a file to IPFS

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const pinataSDK = require("@pinata/sdk");
const pinata = new pinataSDK(
  "ff6d3ff7737e8627277c",
  "462bb62848846981d6d23bcf21e527172d0d2d8bde7a71047d2c4b383dc88207"
);
const { Readable } = require("stream");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

app.use(cors());

function bufferToStream(buffer) {
  const readable = new Readable();
  readable.push(buffer);
  readable.push(null);
  return readable;
}

async function storeOnIPFS(fileBuffer) {
  console.log("Storing file on IPFS");
  try {
    const options = {
      pinataMetadata: {
        name: "MyNFTName",
      },
    };
    const result = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(
      bufferToStream(fileBuffer),
      options
    );
    return result.IpfsHash;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("IPFS Upload Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

app.post("/api/mint", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log("/api/mint route triggered");
  try {
    const fileBuffer = req.file.buffer;
    console.log("Received file buffer:", fileBuffer);

    const ipfsHash = await storeOnIPFS(fileBuffer);
    console.log(`File stored on IPFS with hash: ${ipfsHash}`);

    res.status(200).send({ message: "File stored on IPFS", ipfsHash });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in /api/mint route:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on http://localhost:3000/");
});
```

I have put console logs literally wherever I can to solve it but it does not help. Please!!! I beg for help!

Comment: Can you please tell me what you are inputting as `Title` in your form? Plus if I am right, you didn't need a backend for this. You are, firstly minting the NFT through your front-end, and then minting again using your backend, using the same details

Comment: My title is supposed to be the input from my form labelled NFT Title... I made this backend as future proofing plus i dont know how to use multer any other way cuz this is how i learned it to work, What i discovered that when i extract the mint function from the backend as mint.js and call it, it works perfectly, but when i want to call it from the backend via my frontend through MM it suddenly does not work

Comment: you are right i call minting function twice, i  fixed it now so i only call it in the frontend, but it did not change the fact that MM still rejects it with the same err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the issue, the issue is i had to ditch web3.js and use ethers.js instead